# R Pull From FTP Starts Failing

Tags: r, csv, ftp

Recently had this issue crop up. I pull from an FTP on a bi-monthly schedule into R using a URL string as such:

`url <- "ftp://User:Pass@ftp.myftp.com/"`

I use RCurl syntax to pull fill names and then loop through each name, pulling with `read.csv` with a URL as such:

`myData <- read.csv("ftp://User:Pass@ftp.myftp.com/mycsv.csv")`

This worked two months ago, but has started failing today. It *could* potentially be something has changed in my FTP, but if I drop the above URL in an internet browser, it prompts me to download the file.

Python is able to pull the file, so I feel like I am left with something has changed in R, which I have since updated to 3.4.2 and update RStudio to the current version.

The specific error I get is:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
```

I'm going to attempt to install a downgraded version of RStudio and R to what was 2 months ago to see if this solves it. But in the mean time, any ideas? Is this happening for anyone else? It could even by my IT department potentially putting up some kind of firewall. Really scratching my head here.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Looks like `fread` from `data.table` succeeds. I don't have a clue why `read.csv` has started failing, however.

Comment: `read.csv` dispatches to `read.table` which ultimate calls `download.file`. Look at the help for the latter, there could be a millions reasons. Newer R uses curl natively and _should_ succeed.  I also think `fread` (which I also love) uses the same R functionality to download so ...

Comment: Yeah, I do agree, there could be a million reasons. I tried on an older version of R (3.3.2) and got the same reason. Could even be Windows. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: Also, knowing that it is _turtles all the way down_ is useful as you _can_ tell `download.file()` to use an external `curl` or `wget` binary. I relied on that in the past...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I seem to have found the problem. I went down the rabbit hole to debugging (all the way to the `file` call) and it is using the "default" method, when it needs to use "libcurl". I tried setting `options(download.file.method="libcurl")` like I have seen in other posts, but it doesn't seem to actually change the method. Looking more into, but I very much appreciate the suggestions. Helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going down the debug chain, it seems that I need to set this option to get resolve my issue:

```
options(url.method = "libcurl")
```

The other option:

```
options(download.file.method="libcurl")
```

Only addresses the `download.file` function, and not the `file` function, which `read.csv` was calling. The former addresses `file`.